# Back Home from segued views

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I have used storyboard and segued from Main Menu to dealers list for a district to open Invoices list to Invoice Detail.

Is there a way to put a button called Home, which can send the user back to main menu meaning programmatically invoke back button in Invoice detail, and again invoke back button in open invoice list and again invoke back button in dealer list and send the user to Main menu

Appreciate your inputs
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your button in Storyboard, and wire up a IBAction to it that does this:

```
- (IBAction)homeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
}
```